# Resizing an image before upload in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, html5-canvas

I'm trying to resize an image in a file upload before uploading the image to the server. I found a [decent plugin](https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize/blob/master/README.md) that returns the blob of the updated image, however I cannot find how to assign the blob back to the file object being used by the upload.

The blob looks like: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB.....

```
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        canvasResize(file, {
            width: 300,
            height: 0,
            crop: false,
            quality: 80,
            //rotate: 90,
            callback: function (data, width, height) {
                // How to assign the data blob back to the file?
                //$(file).attr('src', data);

             // THEN submit with the smaller photo   
             $('#PhotoForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've got a data: scheme URI. You could just post that to the server and then decode it back to a binary there.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to send the blob back to the server as text, you won't be able to overwrite the value of the file upload control with a blob.

Answer (score 0):

If you remain stuck with canvasResize, there are a lot of other image manipulating libraries. I've used Pixastic to great effect before, though it has a larger overhead than canvasResize. It is [better documented](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#basic) though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding the blob to a hidden field in the form and submitting it. Saving that as an image from the C# was accomplished with the following:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"data:(?<mime>[\w/]+);(?<encoding>\w+),(?<data>.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var match = regex.Match(input.ImageBlob);
        var mime = match.Groups["mime"].Value;
        var encoding = match.Groups["encoding"].Value;
        var data = match.Groups["data"].Value;
        byte[] imagedata = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

        Image img = byteArrayToImage(imagedata);

        img.Save("someimagename.jpg");
```

Comment: This code with get the proper extension for the image name from the mime type, if needed: http://cyotek.com/blog/mime-types-and-file-extensions